# C++ - Any way to insert an enter into the buffer/Stop cin.ignore requiring enter?

Tags: c++, cin, flush

Pretty much as the title says.
I'm creating a code segment and need to clear the buffer before it in order to start a new input, however, when using `cin.ignore()`, the buffer is cleared but the user is required to hit another enter afterward.
Is there any way I can insert an enter into the buffer to automatically hit enter for the user, or that I can get `cin.ignore` to not require another enter.

I am using `cin.getline` to retrieve the input.

```
void Clear(){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(250, '\n');
}
```

Comment: Shoving a newline in the input stream seems like a Y in an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How about you just don't call this in a context where the isn't already at least one newline already in the `std::cin` input stream in the first place?

Comment: If the user has already input something which you want to ignore, then they will have also pressed enter already, which will be removed by this. If they haven't already input something, then you simply shouldn't call `ignore`.

Answer (score 1):

2 issues:

- The first parameter in the "std::cin.ignore()" that you are using just comes down to a very large number. **This should be the maximum number of characters that the input buffer can hold**. This number may be different on different systems or even header files for different compilers.
- **You need to press enter twice because there is nothing in the buffer to ignore**. It is waiting for something to be entered to ignore. some people will use this to pause the program before the "return 0;".

Comment: How should I go about setting cin.ignore to the maximum number of characters? When I do `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`
it simply causes me to need to press the enter button even more before it runs the getline.

Comment: This isn't the classical behavior of cin.ignore(). Maybe there is also some other problem.